# How to draw a polygon

Tags: modeling

[image]

How can I draw polygons that connect the domes as shown in the image?

Comment: you can also check my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305056/rounded-dice-why-do-the-simplest-things-seem-so-difficult

Answer (score 6):

Probably just start from simple *Cube* and **Bevel Vertex** (Ctrl+Shift+B) ... ?

[image]

[image]

Add *UV Sphere*, delete bottom half and merge by *Bridge Tool* ...

[image]

Comment: Hi, vkl.. Beat me to it! :)  .. Maybe elaborate this with (Shape: 0.5, Clamp Overlap, and Merge by Distance) ? The sort of thing we might take for granted, but  beginner-readers would not.

Comment: Hi Robin :) Sorry, You are right, maybe later ... OP probably needs corner edge (like I tried before https://imgur.com/LqQiLZz but it doesnt end with a tip at bottom ...) so I wanted to wait, since my answer can be wrong.

Comment: True. Topo not great. Then there would be  getting a perfect circle on the top as another step, or calculation. You're ahead of me, as usual :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm late replying due to the PC replacement process. My apologies. I was able to make it the way you showed me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with two cubes quarters, that can be something around this:

[image]

using, mirror on X/Y and a subdivision.

[image] Blender 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've been working on replacing my PC and have delayed my reply. My apologies. I didn't know there was such a way. I hadn't thought of it. Thank you very much.